# Is there an option to turn off the save prompt before quitting in 2.8?

Tags: interface

Seems that now Blender 2.8 is asking if we want to save before quit providing three options: Save, Discard and Cancel.
However, my workflow is fast and I'm more bothered by these questions, especially when I want to load another blend file really fast.
Is there an option to turn off this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can choose to loose all of your work by not saving (and be unbothered), if that is what you want to do...

Disable the **Save Prompt** on the system preferences>Save and Load section.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!